# How to better type a React Context to assume that the value will always be defined and not have to give a default value to `createContext`

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I have a `AuthProvider` at in my application that will automatically redirect to the login page if the user is not logged in

```js
interface IAuthContext {
  token: string | undefined;
}

export const AuthContext = createContext<IAuthContext>({ token: undefined });

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => {
  const [token, setToken] = useState<string | undefined>();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  useEffect(() => {
    const authToken = localStorage.getItem('authToken');

    if (!authToken) {
      navigate('/login');
    }
    setToken(token);
  }, []);

  return <AuthContext.Provider value={{ token }}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
};
```

`MyComp` is a child of `AuthProvider`. Therefore, `token` should always be defined, because if it doesn't exist, then `AuthProvider` will redirect to the login page and `MyComp` will never be rendered.

```js
export const MyComp = () => {
  const { token } = useContext(AuthContext);

  if (!token) {
    throw new Error('missing token');
  }

  const data = useMemo(() => fetchData(token), token);

  return <div>{data}</div>;
};
```

It's annoying having assert that token is not undefined every time I need to use it. I have to type `token` as `string | undefined`, because I need to pass a default value to `createContext`

Is there a way to better type this so I don't need to assert that the token is defined and to not have to give a default value to `createContext`?

Comment: why token is string | undefined ? you can just type it as string no ? then createContext with a null value or an empty object as default value ? `createContext(null as IAuthContext)`.

Comment: I don't want to use 'as', because I then lose typescript type safety. I would prefer to have some sort of error handling in the case that a component was made not a child of the provider by mistake.

Also, if we don't mind using type assertion, a cleaner way would be to use the non-null assertion operator `createContext<IAuthContext>(undefined!)`  https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way using typescript function overloading and a custom react hook

```js
interface IAuthContext {
  token: string;
}

const AuthContext = createContext<IAuthContext | undefined>(undefined);

export function useAuthContext(acceptUndefined: true): IAuthContext | undefined;
export function useAuthContext(): IAuthContext;
export function useAuthContext(acceptUndefined?: true) {
  const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);
  if (!authContext && !acceptUndefined) {
    throw 'The component is not a child of AuthProvider';
  }
  return authContext;
}
```

Then, I can use the `useAuthContext` hook to get a defined context.

```
const MyComp = () => {
  const { token } = useAuthContext();

  const data = useMemo(() => fetchData(token), token);

  return <div>{data}</div>;
};
```

I can also pass `true` to `useAuthContext` if I want to handle the default context value myself

```js
const MyComp = () => {
  const authContext = useAuthContext(true);
  if (!authContext) {
    throw 'AuthContext undefined';
  }
  const { token } = authContext;
  // ... //
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
interface IAuthContext {
  token: string;
}

export const AuthContext = createContext<IAuthContext>({ token: '' });

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => {
  const [token, setToken] = useState('');
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    const authToken = localStorage.getItem('authToken');

    if (!authToken) {
      navigate('/login');
    } else {
      setToken(authToken);
    }
  }, [token]);
  
  if (!token) return null;

  return <AuthContext.Provider value={{ token }}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
};
```

Comment: I don't want to set a default value for token. If one of the attributes of IAuthContext was an object, I would need to give it a default value